# Windows 8.1 - once a day this add appears in bottom right

Tags: windows-8, malware

Once a day, this add appears in my bottom right corner and I've tried all different things to remove it. At first I uninstalled those programs from control panel, then run different antimalware programs that I found in different tutorials on how to remove adds from the bottom right.

Still it appears. When I click on the add, it opens a new tab in internet explorer so I disabled it as well (since it can't be uninstalled in windows 8), but it still appears, but when I click on it now, nothing happens.

If I click on the X, it just closes the add and that's it, but if I press on the minimize button, it gives me a message that I unsubscribed from somewhere, yet it appears next day again.

It appears even if I'm not using any browser. Anybody know the solution? It's really annoying. It usually shows these three adds with that kardashian chick and it takes me to some kind of windows movie maker alike programme website. I know that a girl was using my laptop once, trying to download some video and she installed all these fake plugins and stuff.

[image: I can't post a photo cause the website won't let me do it.]

Comment: Please provide a screenshot.

Comment: upload a pic to imgur, flikr etc & post a link here. Someone with the necessary rep can inline it for you.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/5uPPaCe.png here is the photo

Comment: @Mirza.hophop I've added the screenshot - its waiting for review now

Comment: That is NOT a minimize button. BOTH of those buttons appear simulated and you are clicking through, possibly re-re-re-installing the exploit. Use process explorer or task manager to kill the popup, do not click it.

Comment: Get [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653). When the window appears, drag the crosshair from the Process Explorer toolbar onto the window. It well then highlight the process that opened this window. Add the name and path of this process to your question.

Comment: @Yorik I tried to see what process it is, and there was nothing in task manager. So, it appeared and disappeared on its own, and never appeared again :D

Answer (score 1):

There are normally a few ways to sort this out, you've mentioned you've tried a few but I include a list any way:

Try and uninstall it in Programs and Features.

Run a malware removal program, like Malware bytes

Run an Anti virus program as well, just to be sure!

Check the start up tab in Task Manager and uncheck it if you see it (although this will stop it loading, it won't get rid of it)

Check Task Scheduler to see if anything is scheduled to run which shouldn't be